# How to show the Html tags in ASP: Label in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net

How to show the Html tags in ASP: Label in asp.net?

i was getting the code `<script> </script>` from database. how can show the value in `<asp:label></label>`

If am showing like this

```
<label class="label">
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litProjectType" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectType")%>'></asp:Literal>

</label>
```

The value `<script> </script>` is change into HTML Tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use Server.HtmlEncode function to encode data in html. you can write your code like below:

```
    <label class="label">
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litProjectType" Text='<%# Server.HtmlEncode(Eval("ProjectType"))%>'></asp:Literal>

</label>
```